# Create File when my Spring boot is dockerized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, file

I'm running my Spring Boot application on docker and when I'm trying to create a new object I get this error (the object has an image where it saved in this path locally: `application-fe/src/assets`):

> class path resource [application-fe/src/assets] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/usr/app/target/springbot

Does anyone know how to create a new file inside a docker container?

When running locally I was doing this:

```java
String pathToSave = "application-fe/src/assets";
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(pathToSave);
if (image != null) {
    File fileToSave = new File(resource.getFile() +"\\"+ this.region(region, city) + ".png");
```

Comment: It shouldn't be any different from creating a file outside the container.  Do you know what directory you're currently in, and does that directory exist inside the container?  (Writing files to an application `.../src/...` directory seems like an odd practice, and in a typical Docker image containing only a prebuilt jar file, that directory wouldn't exist.)

Comment: @DavidMaze have you got any idea how may I get the path?

Answer (score 0):

Containers while useful for application isolation, are volatile in nature. Does the file you create require to be accessible or stored outside the container or when the container is not running ?
In that case I would recommend you to add a path in your app.properties and mount that path to your server/laptop.

Use @Value annotations to map absolute path in spring boot and "-v" flag in docker run to map mount path.
Also use mkdir to create the absolute path in your Dockerfile while building the image.

Add below to your Dockerfile:

`RUN mkdir -p /appl/pictures/`    ==> This maybe where you can store your image file from application

In docker run/compose command you can add -v flag as:

```
docker run .... -v <absolute server path>:<image file path inside container> ...
```

eg:

```
docker run .... -v /appl/pictures/:/appl/pictures/ ...
```

So now all images that you create inside container will be mounted into server /appl/pictures/ and will be persistent even if container is destroyed or stopped.

Comment: Hi, when I add an external folder to docker-compose via volume it automaticly save all the file inside it?

Comment: Yes that's right @Sonn
I edited the main comment with sample snippet.

Comment: if I wanna pull my container online the other user can get the content of the folder? Because I got a folder populated with image.png inside where the user can perform the CRUD inside

Comment: If it's a shared folder or certain users have access to it via group, then they should be able to access the images. Basically the point is that now any images created by the application are persistently available in that folder. It's up to you to manage the folder securely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're running inside a Docker container, the problem is that you are running your application from a .jar file.

You're getting the base path to write to using `Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application-fe/src/assets");`.

If you compile the application to a set of .class files on the file system and run this, then the resource is located at an absolute path on the same file system as the .class files. It's likely that you could write to this local file system location.

When you package the compiled classes into a .jar file and run this, then the classpath containing the resource is inside the .jar file. You can't write to a location inside of a .jar file. This is what the `does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/usr/app/target/springbot` error message is trying to tell you.

If you really need to write to a file in the container, you should choose a file system path that is not on the classpath (that is, don't use `ClassPathResource`).

Comment: Hi, when I add an external folder to docker-compose via volume it automaticly save all the file inside it?